# Where does useSelector Pull State from if it is Not Passed In?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

The screenshot below is taken from the Maximilian Schwarzmüller's Udemy Course "React - The Complete Guide (incl Hooks, React Router, Redux)"

When using `useSelector` to access some part of the state, it is not obvious where the state is being passed in. In the screenshot below, Max executes `useSelector` to access the `cartIsVisible` method of the ui reducer - but how does he get access to the state itself? Since the useSelector is just a hook taken from react-redux and there is nothing else passed in, how does he have access to state? When I tried to `console.log(state)` it shows an error that state is not defined.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the `index.js` you should see a `<Provider` wrapping the `App` component as so

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

The `useSelector` hook gets the state from the `redux store` sent in the wrapper `<Provider` component.

The `Provider` makes the Redux store available to the component hierarchy below.

Comment: Got it, now it makes more sense. Because outside of that there really is no way it could have access to the store since useSelector is an outside hook. So the Provider  gives useSelector access to the store since store is passed in to the provider as a value. Do I have that correct?

Comment: Yes, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOZ4Ml9LlWE at 29:12 minutes.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a Redux maintainer and author of the last couple React-Redux versions.

Internally, `useSelector` gets access to the Redux store via a `useContext` hook.  It then calls `store.subscribe()` to be notified any time an action is dispatched, and uses `store.getState()` to get the latest state.  Finally, it calls `yourSelector(state)`.

See my extensive post [The History and Implementation of React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/) and talk [ReactNext 2019: A Deep Dive into React-Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/06/presentation-react-redux-deep-dive/) for more details on how React-Redux works internally.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for this!

Comment: Came across this and I'm struggling with how useSelector seems to get the previous value instead of the updated value after dispatching an async action. When I use the redux dev tools the correct value has been updated but I get the wrong value from useSelector. How can I ensure I get the correct current value before continuing with logic execution?

Comment: You're not "getting the wrong value" per se. When you write `const value = useSelector(state => state.some.value)`, you read a value _at the time the component rendered_. If you dispatch an action later from inside the component, the event handler is a "closure", and _still sees the existing value in that variable_. It's the same situation with React's built-in `setState()`. If you _need_ to access the newly updated Redux state immediately, move that logic into a thunk, which has `getState` available: https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `state` is an argument of the useSelector hook. You cannot console.log `state` because as it belongs to the useSelector hook, I believe it is out of scope in regards to your attempted console.log.

The following is directly from the React Redux [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) on the matter:

> The selector is approximately equivalent to the mapStateToProps argument to connect conceptually. The selector will be called with the entire Redux store state as its only argument. The selector will be run whenever the function component renders (unless its reference hasn't changed since a previous render of the component so that a cached result can be returned by the hook without re-running the selector). useSelector() will also subscribe to the Redux store, and run your selector whenever an action is dispatched.